# How do I convert month number to month name?

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting the date from `MySQL` as `2021-10-30` (YYYY-MM-DD) and storing this date in a variable in JavaScript.
But I want to change `2021-10-30` to `2021-Oct-30`, then how can I do this in javascript ?  I don't want to do this in MySQL.

Comment: What's stopping you? Create an array of month names and index it using the middle part of the date.

Comment: You could also use the `moment.js` library.

Comment: Any other direct solution without creating an array. Like we  can do this without an array in PHP

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have built-in date formatting functions like PHP does.

Comment: Read the linked question, it has over 50 ways to do it.

Comment: Dates in YYYY-MM-DD format are parsed as UTC, so you can use the built–in parser and *toLocale* string with appropriate options: `new Date('2021-10-30').toLocaleString('en-ca',{year:'numeric', month:'short', day:'2-digit', timeZone:'UTC'}).match(/\w+/g).join('-')` gives "2021-Oct-30".

Comment: So now I am currently using `toLocaleString`